# Noncompliant Code Java Infinite Loop SonarQube Bug java:S2189

Tags: java, loops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, static-code-analysis

I get sonar bug with code java:S2189 "Loops should not be infinite". I have explicit condition to finish my loop. Maybe I'm not seeing the problem. Is there a proper explanation for this bug?

It may be related with SonarQube's scanner version. The version difference also changes the situation.

This code has bug for SonarQube Scanner 4.2.0.1873

This code has no bug for SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778

```
public class SonarBug implements Runnable {

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        boolean continueCondition = true;

        while (continueCondition) {

            Integer takenInteger;

            try {
                takenInteger = queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                continueCondition = false;
                continue;
            }

            callSomeFunction(takenInteger);
        }

        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }

    private void callSomeFunction(Integer takenInteger) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if no `InterruptedException` is thrown? And before you say "well, it will happen at a certain point" a code analyzer has no way to prove that.

Comment: As an aside, why not just `break`ing instead of setting that flag and `continue`ing?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca why does it need to prove that it will happen? Is it trying to solve the halting problem or something?

Comment: @Siguza the bug is "this is an infinite loop" and the behavior is "this will only exit if something goes wrong" (which is a low bar to clear, any program does that in a way, so it's irrelevant). Even more stringent in this case: "if a particular exception is thrown". I'm not sure whether it has anything to do with the halting problem, but it seems to me that it has a very good reason to assume there's no way to exit the loop in normal execution. If you take issue with the word "prove" I'm open to suggestions as English is not my native language.

Comment: I take issue with the premise that "loop until something goes wrong" is not a valid approach. That's exactly how I'd implement e.g. a socket handler. Handle messages in an infinite loop until the socket dies. What else are you even supposed to do? Limit the amount of loop iterations to an arbitrary number?

Comment: @Siguza that's fair, but how do you suppose sonarqube would recognize that's what you're trying to do? All it sees is a loop with a condition that becomes false only when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Using break makes a lot of sense. This is my fault. I will try sonar analysis again after I change the code. I'll post the result here.

Comment: While we're having this discussion, I'd like to point out that "sonarqube marked this as a bug" does not automatically mean "we have to change that". In some cases it simply means "are you sure this is what you want to do? because it could lead to this problem". If the answer to that is "yes, I know what I'm doing" you can simply mark the supposed bug as a false positive.

Comment: In other words it's not that "loop until something goes wrong" is not a valid approach. It's just that it has the potential to actually not be what you meant to do and, therefore, be a bug. So sonarqube marks it as such. Then you, as a programmer knowing what you expect the code to do, have to decide whether it is actually a bug or not.

Comment: …and not everyone who added a rule to sonarqube is right.

Comment: I tried putting "break" instead of "continue" and removed the variable "continueCondition" with while(true). Nothing changed. Same result.

Comment: @OnurÖçalan it wasn't meant to be a solution (`while(true)` is still an infinite loop and you're still only breaking in case of an exception), I just found the use of that variable a bit redundant.

Comment: Well, if Sonarqube wants an ending condition, give it an ending condition, `while(!Thread.interrupted()) { Integer takenInteger; try { takenInteger = queue.take(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { break; } callSomeFunction(takenInteger); } Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); System.out.println("Finished.");` That’s still the same logic.